# Setting a factory variable in controller in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, controller, factory

I need to set a factory variable in my controller. This variable is used for the url for returning a save function in my factory. I actually build this url as several pieces but this is a simplified version.

```
myApp.factory('SaveDate', ['$resource',
function saveDateFactory($resource, $http) {
  var myData = '';    
  return $resource(myData, {}, { 
    query: { method: "POST", params: {}, isArray: false },
  });                                                                               
}]);
```

The function from my controller looks like this:

```
vm.myFunction1 = function ($resource) {

  vm.myDate = '/test/MyProduct/SetSalesDate/988093099/108/2016/05/21';

  SaveDate.myData = vm.myDate;

  //this should save the date for milestones  
  SaveDate.query();
  vm.cleanUp();

};
```

I have tried using an object instead of a primitive but it also didn't work. I have tested and my value for SaveDate.myData is being set accurately. If I hard code a value in the spot where I declare my variable in the factory, it will save perfectly. I am just not able to pass the variable successfully from my controller to my factory. I have tried a wide variety of ways to do this including using $watch. Thanks for your help on this!

When I added a function like this:

```
myApp.factory('SaveDate', ['$resource',
function saveDateFactory($resource, $http) {
  var myData = {};
  myData.getMyUrl = function (urlStuff) {
    alert("in SaveDate" + urlStuff);
    return $http.get(urlStuff);
  }

  return $resource(myData.getMyUrl, {}, {  
    query: { method: "POST", params: {}, isArray: false }
```

Adding this function throws the following error: Unknown provider: myDataProvider <- myData <- UserListController

Comment: Make a function in your factory that takes the date param and call the function in your controller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to create a function in your factory as **Clint** said in the comments.

```
myApp.factory('SaveDate', ['$resource',
function saveDateFactory($resource, $http) {
  var myData = '';

  function setMyData(data) {
    myData = data;
  }

  return {
    setMyData: setMyData,
    resource: $resource(myData, {}, { 
      query: { method: "POST", params: {}, isArray: false },
    })
  };                                                                           
}]);
```

In your controller:

```
SaveDate.setMyData(vm.myDate);
```

Comment: I am getting this error since adding this- SaveDate.query is not a function. Any ideas on this?

Comment: It's `SaveData.resource` now.

Comment: Calling this as SaveDate.resource does not throw an error but it also fails to save the data.

Comment: How do you call it? If it was `SaveDate.query()` before then it should be `SaveDate.resource().query()` now.

Comment: `SaveData.resource.query()`, typo there, sorry!

Comment: I can't thank you enough for your help on this!! Sometimes we get tripped up on what should be an easy little process.